# Games in which one agent may not know if it's playing a game

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

I am investigating a setting where one agent, $P_1$, may not know if the other agent, $P_2$, is present in the system. Thus, $P_1$ is unsure whether it is actually playing a game or simply taking actions and receiving rewards in absence of the other agent.

Have such games been studied? If so, do they have a name? Perhaps such situations can simply be modeled as $P_2$ having a type (exists, doesn't exist) where $P_1$ doesn't know the type.

Comment: What determines whether $P_2$ exists?

Comment: @Micah Let's say $P_2$ exists with some probability $p$ that $P_1$ does not know.

Comment: What kind of behavior do you expect of $P_2$? Greedy, deterministic, randomized? In some circumstances Q-learning provides optimal (or expected optimal) actions whether or not there is a competing agent. In that sense it might not matter.

Comment: If $P_2$ isn't present why wouldn't you consider it still a game?  Incidentally, the setting you describe is equivalent in every way I can tell to another game where both players are always present, but there is a hidden (to $P_1$) flag. If this flag is set, $P_2$ plays as normal. If this flag is not set, then everything $P_2$ does has no effect.

Comment: @Hurkyl Interesting point. In that sense, think falls within the class of asymmetric information games.